# From Dockerfile to Docker-compose

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have created a DockerFile like this:

```
FROM openjdk:14-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/edms-influx-device-fixer-1.2.1.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} device-fixer-1.2.1.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c","java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod device-fixer-1.2.1.jar "]
```

How do I get a docker-compose that allows me to run my Spring Boot project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file called `docker-compose.yml` with the below contents (you can read more about [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) here):

```
version: '3.9'

services:
    your_name:
        build: .
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
```

And then run it:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Run `docker ps` to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your Dockerfile and the project in folder `backend`. Then you can write for example

```
backend:
      build:
       context: ./backend
      environment:
       - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
```

I would remove the spring profile in the dockerfile, but thats a matter of taste.